# How to change value of variable in sass for multiple media queries

Tags: css, sass

SCSS:

```
$thick : 3px;
$pad : 0.5em;
$extra : calc(#{$pad} * 1.2);
$color : #8DC73F;

.footer__links {
  a {
    color: #333;
    padding: $pad $extra;
    display: inline-block;
    border: $thick solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 0.07em;
    }
}
```

I want to change the value of `$pad` for different media queries.

For example:

```
mobile --> $pad : 0.3em, tablet --> $pad : 0.5em
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Sass Variables with CSS3 Media Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122195/using-sass-variables-with-css3-media-queries)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be better to create separate variables.
For example :

```
$space-xs = 4px;
$space-s = 8px;
$space-m = 16px;
$space-l = 32px;
$space-xl = 64px;
```

I strongly recommend you to read this article:
https://medium.com/eightshapes-llc/space-in-design-systems-188bcbae0d62

It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create separate variable or you can override your $pad into media query as well.
Example :

$pad:3px;
@media (min-width:320px){

  $pad:10px;

  .footer__links {
  a {
      color: #333;
    padding: $pad $extra;
    display: inline-block;
    border: $thick solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 0.07em;

}
} 
This give 10px padding to .footer__links a in min screen width 320px
```