# How to Use Bootstrap spacer variable under media query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am using custom `$spacer` variable for adjusting UI/page multiple elements size. how to use this under `@media` query? As below its not working. how to use different $spacer for different resolution? pls help.

```
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  $spacer: 16px;
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  $spacer: 24px;
}
```

Comment: You can not use Sass variables inside media queries as media query happens on client side. Please follow this thread for your preferred solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122195/using-sass-variables-with-css3-media-queries