# How to change SCSS variable based on media query?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, bootstrap-5, darkmode

I'm using Bootstrap in my project and I would like to change the **body-bg** variable based on the user's system color preferences.

It's the initial value:

```
$body-bg: #fff;
```

I am trying to change with using this media query:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  $body-bg: #000;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to change this variable?

Comment: Unfortunately you can’t do that. What you likely need are css custom properties/ css variables: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: A better answer is already provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122195/using-sass-variables-with-css3-media-queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Sass Variables with CSS3 Media Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122195/using-sass-variables-with-css3-media-queries)

Comment: Yes, it was helpful. Thank you.