# Why does SASS error on a valid media query variable: "X isn't a valid CSS value"

Tags: css, sass

I'm hitting a error when I use a variable for a media query. I have trivially reproed the issue here:

```
$media-xs: screen and (max-width: 480px);

// no errors
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .blu { color: blue; }
}

// throws error
@media #{$media-xs} {
  .blu { color: blue; }
}
```

The output when I run this via CLI is:

```
$ sass test.scss test.css

Error: (max-width: 480px) isn't a valid CSS value.
   ╷
13 │ @media #{$media-xs} {
   │          ^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
test.scss 13:10  root stylesheet
```

Comment: Hi, a think u need use "<ur code>" 

```scss
$media-xs: "screen and (max-width: 480px)";

// no errors
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .blu { color: blue; }
}

// no errors
@media #{$media-xs} {
  .blu { color: blue; }
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible according to these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsass%5D+variable+media+query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Sass Variables with CSS3 Media Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122195/using-sass-variables-with-css3-media-queries)

Comment: @A.L. TY, I reviewed "Using Sass..." and a linked one, but they were not this issue.  They dealt with modifying vars inside queries.

Comment: @Valery TY, Your suggestion to quote the query value worked out. I also found that I could concat in another variable. My actual environment is more complex and the actual value comes from another var. It looked like this:
`scss $media-xs: "screen and (max-width: 480px)";`
I want to find documentation to support this and I'll post it as an answer unless one is submitted in a day.

Answer (score 1):

Per suggestion from @Valery Nosareu the value of the SASS variable should have been quoted so that

```
$media-xs: screen and (max-width: 480px);
```

becomes

```
$media-xs: "screen and (max-width: 480px)";
```